# Why is branching is locking a project build for copying .DLL file?

Tags: c#, tfs, branch

I have a `MAIN` solution which holds a host of projects - the whole solution is building fine. So, I go ahead and take a branch of the `MAIN` to a new branch called `DEVELOPMENT`, now there is a single project in there which for some reason is now displaying the error message:

> Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\Delta.PDF.dll" to "bin\x86\Debug\Delta.PDF.dll". Access to the path 'bin\x86\Debug\Delta.PDF.dll' is denied.

Which for the life of me I can't understand seeing as all I have done is a TFS branch - Just wondering if anyone has any suggestions for this

[Unable to copy a file from obj\Debug to bin\Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625239/unable-to-copy-a-file-from-obj-debug-to-bin-debug)

From the above answer I thought I could of locked a process of some sorts so I logged off my machine but it's still there. The branch is in the same parent directory as main just in a different sub-folder. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I had been trying to clean the solution in order to do what Jacooobley said (clear the debug) but this was for some reason keeping my .DLL in there, a manual delete did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the .DLL from the debug folder and then rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use Process Explorer from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) to find which process has locked this file - use the Find menu to search for Delta.PDF.dll; this should give you a clue as to why the file is locked and what you can do about it (e.g., exit the locking process).