# Unable to copy file .exe in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have an asp.net core project that references .NET Framework and I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. When I try to build my solution, I came across with this error:

```
Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\net461\MyProject.exe" to "bin\Debug\net461\MyProject.exe". 
Access to the path 'bin\Debug\net461\MyProject.exe' is denied.
```

Even if I cleaned the solution and build again, I still have this error.

Anyone faced this error?

Comment: You probably have the program running. You need to kill it.

Comment: This solution solves my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73686473/12678101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Task Manager and look for Microsoft*vshost*.exe and kill them all. Even though you stop debugging the exe can continue to run in the background. This causes a lock on the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ottak. I also had to close my antivirus for a while, it looked like it was holding that file.

Answer (score 1):

Close the application and delete Obj and bin folder

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the .net core localhost server stopped, before trying to build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error before. Trying the following has worked for me:

```
1. Close the current solution.
2. Close Visual Studio.
3. Start Visual Studio in Administrator mode.
4. Re-open and build the solution.
```

The above can avoid the common copy file and file Access Denied errors.